# thread using 100% of core

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt

Is there a way to use multiple cores for one thread? I am presently using Qt on Ubuntu with an i7

Comment: How about multiple threads to run on multiple cores?  That is how it is done when you can split the workload between cores/threads.

Comment: What are you doing that it is eating up your CPU? Sounds more like an implementation problem (unless the computations are truly that intensive) - rather the looking to running multiple cores, why not look at refactoring? Make sure, for any infinite loops, you have some sort of blocking (e.g. usleep(10000) for a 10ms sleep at the end of each loop) - this will save your CPU and 10ms will, in most cases, go practically undetected.

Comment: @RageD I'm testing the limits of a process.  I am optimizing signal data to render on a widget as a graph before the user seeks through it, zooms in and out etc.  Think of it as I want to decode a whole movie before watching it and I must use a lossless codec (though this is not constant time sampling but rather event based).  I could let the user start using some of the data while I optimize the rest.  True I haven't tried to put this code in its own thread but it was easier to create it as a single thread in the beginning.  Maybe now is the time to look into puting it in its own thread(s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You can run one thread per core. You can run many threads on one core via time sharing. But you cannot run one thread on two cores. (Not at the same time, but it can switch between cores).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. If you want to make use of more than one core, split your work into more than one thread or process.

Welcome to the world of multithreaded programming. Wait until we have 16 cores, then 32, then...

Comment: I'm sure they will come up with something as more and more cores could mean limiting single threads too much at a certain point. I'm sure someone will figure how to do this in the Hardware someday.

Answer (score 4):

No. A thread can run on only one CPU core at a time.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a thread can only occupy one core at a time.  Think of a thread like the "atom" of processing.

If you want to spread the processing over multiple cores, try splitting up your task into smaller chunks and assigning a thread to each of them.  Don't go too crazy though -- there is most certainly a bit of overhead for creating each one.